# add a button to all pushed viewControllers' navigation bar which performs an action from main navigation controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

NavigationController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol NavigationControllerDelegate;
@interface NavigationController : UINavigationController<UINavigationControllerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic , assign)id<NavigationControllerDelegate , UINavigationControllerDelegate> delegate;
-(void)cancelImagePicker:(id)sender;
@end
@protocol NavigationControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)mediaPickerController:(NavigationController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info;

- (void)mediaPickerControllerDidCancel:(NavigationController *)picker;

@end
```

NavigationController.m

```
#import "NavigationController.h"
#import "DataViewController.h"
@interface NavigationController ()
@end

@implementation NavigationController
@synthesize delegate;

-(id)init{
    UIViewController *controller = [[DataViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DataViewController" bundle:nil];
    self = [super initWithRootViewController:controller];
    if (self) {
        self.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"Data Table";
        self.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                                        style:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancelImagePicker:)];
        self.navigationBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)cancelImagePicker:(id)sender{
    [delegate mediaPickerControllerDidCancel:self];   
}
@end
```

DataViewController.m

```
.....
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    secondViewController *secondController = [[secondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"secondViewController" bundle:nil ];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: secondController animated:YES];
}
.......
```

I want to add a "cancel" button on secondViewController's navigation bar which performs the action `-(void)cancelImagePicker:(id)sender;` from `NavigationController.m`. And the same for pushed third, fourth and fifthViewController. How can this be achieved? Do i have to write code in each viewController or  Can i write in common?

I have presented the `NavigationController` from `MainViewController` on buttonClick as

```
- (IBAction)navView:(id)sender {
    NavigationController * controller = [[NavigationController alloc]init];
    controller.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

and implemented the delegation methods there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use notification center instead of delegates, the idea is,

```
[NSNotificationCenter DefaultCenter] addObserver]
```